# jquery - how do i make a div slide left 100px everytime i click a link

Tags: jquery, slide

What i have so far is this

```
$(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'100px'},'slow');                  
    });            
});
```

Heres a link [to a demo](http://tinyurl.com/3sfk8xh)

Which works only once, but if i try to click the link again, Nothing happens

how do I make it so it works more like a slideshow? so everytime I click, it slides left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. You use `+=` expression:

```
$(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({left:'+=100px'},'slow');                  
    });            
});
```