# Switch 2 Floating Divs with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-float

Hi I have updated the code to have 2 divs with different sizes. They need to switch positions with animation using css floats.

please see the code so far - http://jsfiddle.net/jz5VW/

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#switch').click(function () {
        jQuery('#one').animate({
            left: jQuery("#two").offset().left - jQuery("#featured-top").offset().left
        });
        jQuery('#two').animate({
            right: jQuery("#two").offset().left - jQuery("#featured-top").offset().left
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way for them to float right and left of the wrapper?

Thanks so much!

Comment: By animation you mean, it should be a visible transition of both to the other floating value?

Comment: Yes, like 2 blocks crossing each other switching positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a switch with transition animation you can use this snipped:

```
$(function() {
   $('#switch').click(function() {
      $('#one').animate({left:$("#two").offset().left}); 
      $('#two').animate({right:$("#two").offset().left});
   });
});
```

[jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/9/)

you just have to keep in mind the padding and margin options...

with wrapper:

```
$(function () {
   $('#switch').click(function () {
       $('#one').animate({
           left: $("#two").offset().left-$("#wrapper").offset().left
       });
       $('#two').animate({
           right: $("#two").offset().left-$("#wrapper").offset().left
       });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Hi this works very well, only problem is when the two blocks lie in a wrapper, they jump out the wrapper when the window resizes or a smaller screen - http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/16/

Comment: Hi i have changed the divs to different sizes, can you please look at the fiddle and see why the jump onto each other? thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will do a trick:

```
$("#switch").on("click", function () {
    $(".square").each(function () {
        var floatEl = ($(this).css("float") == "left") ? "right" : "left";
        $(this).css("float", floatEl);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/2/)

[Example with animation](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/10/)

Comment: Hi thank you, is there a way to animate them switching positions?

Comment: Take a look at second example.

Comment: @Morpheus: big fan of your jquery powers :)

Answer (score 0):

**Switching Float Values:**
There can be multiple way to do this. Check JQuery `removeClass(...)`, `addClass(...)` documentation on [JQuery Website](http://api.jquery.com)

You can also check the `css(...,...)` method documentation on the same website to achieve this.

To animate the divs, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440112/jquery-how-do-i-make-a-div-slide-left-100px-everytime-i-click-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jquery .animate()
This isn't pretty, and you will need to use dynamic values for the shift.
[Simple dummy animation](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/12/)

```
$('#switch').on("click", function ()  { 
    $('#one').animate({
        right: '-=500',
      }, 5000, function() {})
    $('#two').animate({
        right: '+=500',
      }, 5000, function() {})
});
```